# Transfer Data from NodeJS to C++ Application

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I want to transfer information from nodejs to embedded C++ Application running on Linux Platform. Is this possible?

The main program is written in C++ and the software updater (Node JS) is a standalone application which is called from the main C++ program.

I would like explain the environment in which the data transfer is going to occur. It is as follows :

1. Main C++ application calls the standalone NodeJS application
2. Node JS makes a SOAP call and get the available s/w update names from web
3. The names are then passed to the main application and main application (user) chooses which software update to download.
4. Node JS then downloads the software update and exits.

Is this data transfer possible?

Thanks

Comment: WTH is a _standalone NodeJS application_?

Comment: It is just a separate application on the same system. lol

Comment: TCP, UDP, Unix Sockets, IPC message queues?

Answer (score 1):

Well, Some questions:

How main app transfer data to node app ? Parameters ? Environment variables?
HOw node return the data to main application? Stdout ? some RPC ? Shared memorie, Message queues ?

There's a ton of ways of doing it We Need mode details to helps you

Any way, a simple example that will work

- Main app calls node app like with Argument "MakeTheSOARequest"

  ```
  node app "makeTheSOARequest"
  ```
- Node make the call and print results to a new files, and exits
- Main app read the file, do their bussiness  and call node app again
  with arguments

  ```
  node app --download swudtae1, swupdate2 .. swupdateN
  ```
- Node app downloads the required files and exits

Answer (score 1):

People are suggesting strange ways to transfer the data (I mean, shared memory, seriously? IPC message queues? come on). The most obvious way to pass data in such a case is to use command line arguments and standard output.

Here is an example of a Node app that fakes getting and downloading the updates. If invoked without arguments, it gets available updates and prints them on standard output. If invoked with arguments, it downloads the updates specified as arguments.

The main application is a shell script for simplicity (but you could invoke the Node program from C, C++ or any other language that lets you run external programs). It runs the Node application first to get available updates, then it selects just the first two of them and then runs the Node app again to download just those two updates.

The `getUpdates()` and `downloadUpdates()` are mockups that return example data but you can do whatever you need inside of them to return real data.

#### nodeapp.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

'use strict';

function getUpdates() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    console.error('Getting available updates ...');
    setTimeout(() => {
      var updates = ['update1', 'update2', 'update3']; 
      console.error('Available updates:', updates.join(', '));
      res(updates); 
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function downloadUpdates(list) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    console.error('Downloading updates:', list.join(', '));
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.error('Download complete.');
      res(); 
    }, 3000);
  });
}

if (process.argv.length < 3) {
  getUpdates()
    .then(updates => {
      updates.forEach(i => console.log(i));
      process.exit(0);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Error:', err);
      process.exit(1);
    });
} else {
  var updates = process.argv.slice(2);
  downloadUpdates(updates)
    .then(() => {
      process.exit(0);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Error:', err);
      process.exit(1);
    });
}
```

#### mainapp.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo GETTING AVAILABLE UPDATES
available=(`./nodeapp.js`)
echo GOT AVAILABLE
wanted="${available[0]} ${available[1]}"
echo TRYING TO DOWNLOAD: $wanted
./nodeapp.js $wanted && echo DONE || echo ERROR
```

The shell script prints everything in uppercase to make it visible which program prints which message. The result of running `./mainapp.sh` is:

```
GETTING AVAILABLE UPDATES
Getting available updates ...
Available updates: update1, update2, update3
GOT AVAILABLE
TRYING TO DOWNLOAD: update1 update2
Downloading updates: update1, update2
Download complete.
DONE
```

No IPC, no shared memory, no TCP, UDP or Unix sockets. Just plain old arguments and stdout.